# In search of a simpler approach - and something easier on the eyes

Tags: c#, linq

How would you re-write the following, so it's a bit easier on the eyes?

```
Func<DateTime, String> formatter = null;

formatter = new Func<DateTime, String>(d =>
{
    var r = "";

    foreach (var i in new[] { d.Day, d.Month, d.Year })
    {
        if (i < 10) r += "0";

        r += i.ToString();
    }

    return r;
});
```

Comment: Easy on my eyes.  Highly subjective question.

Comment: I consider this to be a good [Code Review](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/) candidate.

Comment: `formatter(new DateTime(2011,4,14))` produces `"140442011"`. Is that what you want?

Comment: @Mortinho: No. That is a typo :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I'd rewrite it as:

```
Func<DateTime, String> formatter = d => d.ToString("ddMMyyyy", 
    CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

Only difference here is that for dates before 1000AD, this will pad to 4 digits instead of 2...

EDIT: As noted in comments, this doesn't replicate the bug in the original code - it would format (say) a month of 5 as "055". The simplest way to fix this in the original code would be:

```
if (i < 10) r += "0";
r += i;
```

(But I'd prefer my code anyway :)

Comment: this. it doesn't get easier than this.

Comment: Unfortunately this is not quite the same :P with the code in the OP when you run `formatter(new DateTime(2011,4,14))` you get `"140442011"`. (I bet it's a bug in the OP code, though).

Comment: Your code gives `"14042011"`. Let me break them down: "14-044-2011" vs "14-04-2011". See the duplicated 4 in the month? I think the OP missed an `else`.

Comment: @Martinho: Ah, indeed I'd missed the duplicated 4. Will edit my answer to point out the bug.

Answer (score 2):

I like Jon Skeets answer best, but I'd like to offer an alternative:

```
Func<DateTime, String> formatter = d => string.Format(
    "{0:00}{1:00}{2:00}", 
    d.Day, d.Month, d.Year);
```

I always check this site for string formatting: http://blog.stevex.net/string-formatting-in-csharp/

Answer (score 1):

Any reason not to exchange the entire formatter code with a `ToString("ddMMyyyy")`?

Comment: Is "yyyy" guaranteed to be 4 digits, no matter what `CultureInfo` is used? I'm not so sure...

Comment: I'm pretty sure. The information here seems to confirm it: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4.aspx. Formats like "ddd" **is** culture specific and will display differently for different cultures.

Comment: I think you're right. The documentation is very clear about this. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

```
Func<DateTime, String> formatter = d => d.ToString("ddMMyyyy");
```